# nodejs & kubernetes : How to do a deployment rollout restart (nodejs)

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, orchestration

I'd like to do a `rollout restart` using nodejs, but I can't find the relevant API :

`kubectl rollout restart deployment/myApp`

Could you please help?

P.S : I'd like to avoid the scaling to 0 and then to N.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually nothing that you should have to do. But what you can do is to **add** or **update** and annotation in the `template:`-part of the Deployment, this will trigger a new deployment.

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
      annotations:
        dummy: hello   # this is a new annotation
```